# Intranet ASP.NET MVC application with longer session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, session-state

I am developing an intranet ASP.NET MVC 4.5 application for almost 2000 users (and **~1200 concurrent users**) with **Windows Authentication**. The requirement is to have the **session alive for 8 hours**. I am storing only two varaibles in session objects ID and Name in **Session_Start** (in Global.asax.cs). There are few variables stored in jQuery session (not on the server)

The session settings in Web.Config:

If there is a session timeout then I am redirecting the user to the home page (created a **BaseController** and overriding **OnActionExecuting** function).

1. Is the above approach good? Any better solution?
2. Can I keep the session alive for 8 hours?
3. Will there be any load issues on the IIS server (version 7.5) ?

EDIT:
I am also recycling the AppPool at scheduled time (7 pm daily).

Answer (score 2):

The Timeout property can be set up to a value of 525,600 minutes (1 year). The default value is 20 minutes. On the other hand, note that you will have performance issues if you have large number of users as it increases in session timeout, your inactive sessions will remain in Web server memory which may cause application pool to recycle, which would result in loosing all sessions for all users.

You can set the session timeout in web.config as shown below:

***web.config:***

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="1800" />

    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />    

    <!-- For LDAP -->
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">

        <!-- Note: I also remove this part and try with only "sessionState" -->
        <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="1" 
            slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

On the other hand, if you use `ASP.NET Identity` you do not need to use settings in `web.config`. Just add these two lines to your `UseCookieAuthentication()` method as shown below:

```
....,
SlidingExpiration = true,
ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
...
```

So, the final code of your method will be as shown below:

***Startup.Auth.cs:***

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Code removed for brevity.

    // Configure the sign in cookie
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        },            
        SlidingExpiration = true, 
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) //Set the session timeout at here
    });            
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);        
}
```

**Update:**

Regarding to the second issue, the problem is related to `IIS` rather than the schedulers `Quartz.NET`, `Hangfire`, etc. On the other hand, there are lots of solution methods posted on the web, but only some of them is working. In my opinion, there is no need to apply lots of configuration settings. Just install [Keep Alive Service For IIS 6.0/7.5](https://keepalive.codeplex.com/) on the server to which you publish your application and enjoy. Then your published application will be alive after application pool recycling, IIS/Application restarting, etc.

Comment: I am recycling AppPool daily 7 pm and using Windows Authentication.

Comment: See my update above and try to use Keep Alive Service on IIS Server where you publish your application.

Comment: Thanks, Murat. The answer didn't actually answer my questions however maybe useful for someone else.